# Multithreaded Server in c++ : Memory leakage

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a multithreaded server in c++(linux). My problem is that my code runs fine for initial few requests but after that it shows "free:Invalid pointer". I know this error can come from any part of my code but for the below snippet I want to know suggestions if I am going on right track.

// This is helper function used in pthread_create

```
void *Parse::serveRequest_helper(void *c)
{

  Parse *P1 =(Parse *)c;
  P1->serveRequest();
}
```

// On this function 10 threads are continously working

```
void Parse::serveRequest()
{
  pthread_detach(pthread_self());
  while(1)
   {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&print_lock);
       if(requestqueue.empty())
          pthread_cond_wait(&print_cond, &print_lock);
       SendData *S = new SendData;
       clientInfo c;
       cout<<"Inside Serving thread"<<endl;
       c = requestqueue.front(); //assuming this queue has data coming from   some other scheduler thread function 
       requestqueue.pop();
       S->requestPrint(c);
       delete S;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_lock);
           cout<<" Inside Thread is out"<<endl;
   }
 }
```

// Below function I am using to write data of the file to socket.

// When a thread will handle this function, the file pointer will be local to the thread or for all 10 threads it will be global .. ?

```
void SendData::requestPrint(clientInfo c)
{

if (write(c.accept,"Requested File Data :", 21) == -1)
            perror("send");
ifstream file;
file.open(c.filename.c_str());
if (file.is_open())
{
      string read;
      while (!file.eof() )
      {
          getline(file,read);
          if (write(c.accept, read.c_str(), (size_t)read.size()) == -1)
              perror("send");

      }

}
file.close();
close(c.accept);
}
```

Comment: On which operating system are you testing your program? With which compiler? If on Linux, compile with `g++ -Wall -g`, improve the code till you get no warnings at all, use `valgrind` to hunt memory leaks, and `gdb` for debugging.

Comment: I am using linux and when i use valgrind sometimes it shows  pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1 (allocatestack.c:561)... I nevr used valgrind before so I am not able to test using it properly.

Comment: and I get warning in "void *Parse::serveRequest_helper" function...but what should I return from this function ...If i return then my thread will stop.

Comment: mixing references and pointers is not a really good idea in my view, references offers an implicit behaviour and for this reason they behave really bad when you encounter a NULL value, basically because a reference does not need an explicit indirection, it just assume that an address should be used to get a value. Pointers on the other hand are more trivial at runtime if compared to references ( again, in my opinion ) but they offer some challenges is some key steps like the casting or the values that they can assume, or possible memory leaks.

Comment: debugging an application that uses both references and pointers it's harder than debugging one with just one of them, and probably you don't need pointers and you are better using references that are more like the C++ of doing things, especially when it comes to type safety and memory leaks.

Comment: But I tried with reference as well but that too led to no success...so i tried this approach ...still no luck .. :(

Comment: I am not sure ..But if I return Null from my void * function then the thread will exit .. correct me if I am wrong ..?